# Combine 2 sources of cookie in 1

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cookies, salesforce

Our website have 2 cookie sources, 1 from Salesforce to track the user engagement and another one from our website. Is there a way to integrate both of them in the cookie from our website, we need that because when you access the website is showing 2 cookie to accept. For cookie we are using CookieYes plugin.
You can have a look here: https://www.wastetrade.com/

I tried to hire an event , when press one button the second one to be pressed automatically but didn't work.